# Unity ARKit Objective C Apple Mach-O Linked (Id) Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, arkit

I’m working on a QR reader for a Unity 2017.2 ARkit project and I have run into some trouble trying to build my project with X Code 9.0.  The error message is an Apple Mach-O Linker

[image]

I’ve haven’t written my objective C project yet, but have ran into some trouble with the CIImage.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//static float qrcodeBounds[8];
static volatile BOOL reading = false;

void ReadQRCode(long long mtlTexPtr)
{
   if (reading) return;
   reading = YES;

   MTLTextureRef mtlTex = (__bridge MTLTextureRef)(void*)mtlTexPtr;
   CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithMTLTexture:mtlTex options:nil];
}

void GetQRCodeBounds(int32_t **boundsPtr){ 

}
```

The error which I get is an Undefined symbol for architecture arm64:

[image]

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage) says that that `CIImage` class is declared in CoreImage framework. So you need to add this framework to your project if you didn't. If you have CoreImage framework imported to your project try adding `#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>` to your source file where you use `CIImage`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a framework, that requires this. 
Try to add coreImage framework